# Sencha Touch - Cannot generate first app

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I just downloaded Sencha Touch 2.1.0 and Sencha CMD v.3.0.2.288. I extracted the Sencha Touch SDK into MAMP's htdocs folder. When I tried following the getting started guide,

```
sencha app create MyApp ../MyApp
```

gives the error

```
Sencha Cmd v3.0.2.288
[ERR]       No such property : 'create'
```

I am guessing that the `create` argument is not available in this version of Sencha Cmd. I tried

```
sencha app build MyApp ../MyApp
```

I get the error

```
Sencha Cmd v3.0.2.288
[ERR]       'MyApp' not in valid range: [native, package, testing, production]
[ERR]       Illegal value : MyApp
```

Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To generate a new app you need to:

`cd path/to/sencha-touch-2.1/directory` and then run:

`sencha generate app MyApp path/to/MyApp`

Then to build your app:

`cd path/to/MyApp` and run:

`sencha app build native`

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and received an error: `Failed to determine framework name.  Please ensure this command was issued from either a framework or application directory`. I downloaded the `sencha-touch-2.1.0-commercial` version.

Comment: Is `Sencha Cmd` in your path?

Comment: is compass mandatory for sencha touch build ??? or can we avoid it as i will not be doing any css changes??

Comment: I tried this command and it worked. "sencha --debug app package build packager.json"   did not complain anything on compass during build